# check if an input is a float

Tags: python, calculator

I am starting learning Python and tried to build a simple calculator. I want to make my program check if `number_1` and `number_2` are really floats, and if they aren't, start the calculation again. Does anyone know a solution to my problem?

```py
def calculate():

    operator = input("What operator do you wanna use(*,/,+,-)? ")
    possible_op = ["*", "+", "-", "/"]
    possible_classes = ["<class 'float'>", "<class 'int'>"]

    if operator not in possible_op:
        calculate()
    number_1 = float(input("What is your first number? "))
    if number_1.type != "Float" or "Int":
        calculate()
    number_2 = float(input("What is your second number? "))
    if (type(number_2)) not in possible_classes:
        calculate()

    
    if operator == "+":
        print(number_1 + number_2) 
    elif operator == "-":
        print(number_1 - number_2) 
    elif operator == "*":
        print(number_1 *  number_2) 
    elif operator == "/":
        print(number_1 / number_2) 
    else:
        print("Wrong Input")
        calculate()

    again()
```

Comment: You could try ```if isinstance(number1, np.float64) != True: ...```

Comment: You explicitly made them floats. No reason to check it then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use recursion for this kind of looping.  Remember that every recursive call uses more and more memory to save all the new local variables.

Also, your "wrong input" clause can never be hit -- you have already checked that the operator is one of the ones you support.

```
def calculate():
    while True:
        operator = input("What operator do you wanna use(*,/,+,-)? ")
        possible_op = "+-*/"

        if operator not in possible_op:
            continue
        try:
            number_1 = float(input("What is your first number? "))
            number_2 = float(input("What is your second number? "))
        except ValueError:
            continue
    
        if operator == "+":
            print(number_1 + number_2) 
        elif operator == "-":
            print(number_1 - number_2) 
        elif operator == "*":
            print(number_1 *  number_2) 
        elif operator == "/":
            print(number_1 / number_2) 
        break
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this can help you, is a separated function that if the given number is float return True or False

```
def is_float(number):
  if isinstance(number, float):
     return True
  else:
     return False
```

You can call it in your code like this, you pass the number in this case number_1 as a parameter:

```
if is_float(number_1):
  # do something
```

Comment: I don't know if you meant to do this. but you can go like `return isinstance(number, float)` in the `is_float` function. Maybe you meant to not do this to keep it simple

Answer (score 1):

`float()` will always either return a `float` or raise a `ValueError`, so there's no point to checking the type of the return after you call `float()`; either it'll be a `float` or you'll never reach that line of code because the uncaught exception will end the execution of the function.  Instead you want to use `try/except`:

```
    try:
        number_1 = float(input("What is your first number? "))
        number_2 = float(input("What is your second number? "))
    except ValueError:
        return calculate()
```

Note that using recursion to loop in Python is generally a bad idea because Python doesn't optimize tail calls like many other languages do.  Instead you should use a `while`, e.g.:

```
possible_op = {
    "*": float.__mul__,
    "+": float.__add__,
    "-": float.__sub__,
    "/": float.__truediv__,
}

while True:
    operator = input("What operator do you wanna use(*,/,+,-)? ")
    if operator not in possible_op:
        continue
    try:
        number_1 = float(input("What is your first number? "))
        number_2 = float(input("What is your second number? "))
    except ValueError:
        continue

    print(possible_op[operator](number_1, number_2))
    break
```

Comment: But please fix the horrible abuse of recursion for this case.  It should be a `while True`.

Comment: I'd use corresponding methods from [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) instead of `float.__mul__`

Comment: but what color will we paint the bikeshed?

Comment: Blue and yellow, obviously.

Comment: Or rather Lapis Lazuli and Sunglow, [apparently](https://www.schemecolor.com/python-logo-colors.php).

Answer (score 0):

`type()` method returns the class type of the argument passed as parameter. You have to check whether the returned class type is an instance of the class, float.

You can do that by,
`isinstance(number_1, float)`

This will return a boolean value. If `number_1` is a float value, it will return `True`, else it will return `False`.

Comment: The input that needs checking is a string, so this is not going to work. OP wants to know if the input can safely be converted to a float, not if it already is a float.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.isnumeric()` to check if the user input a number here's how:

```
number1 = input("What is your first number? ")
number2 = input("What is your second number? ")

if number1.isnumeric() and number2.isnumeric():
    number1 = float(number1)
    number2 = float(number2)
```

`.isnumeric()` checks if all of the things in a string are a number. If so it returns `True` otherwise it returns `False`

Note that if that number has a decimal point it will return `False`. You can split the numbers behind the decimal point and the numbers in front of it, then check if they're both numeric. But you're better off just using a `try-except` statement instead. But if you only wanted integers then `.isnumeric()` is perfect for you

and that should work, thanks.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `isnumeric` will return `False` for a decimal number. You will have to split it on the `.` and check all tokens.

Comment: Oh yeah, I'll edit my answer so it says that

Answer (score 0):

Your `possible_classes` list is a list of strings, not classes. `"<class 'int'>"` is the string representation of the `type` object, not the type object itself, so `type(1) in ["<class 'int'>"]` would always return `False`.

I'd recommend using the try/except method suggested by a few others or use `isinstance()` for a single class, but if you specifically want to check against a list of multiple classes, something like this could work:

```py
possible_classes = [float, int]
# instead of possible_classes = ["<class 'float'>", "<class 'int'>"]

if type(var) not in possible_classes:
    # ...
```